# How can I run a future before build in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am not able to run getMapCurrencies before the build, and I need values in listCurrencies before the view. I can not put the future builder in the build because I dont want to bring listCurrencies many times, just once.

Please help

```
getMapCurrencies() {
    currencies.getCurrenciesCheck().then((val) {
      listCurrencies = val;
    });
  }

class _CurrencyWidgetState extends State<CurrencyWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    getMapCurrencies();
    super.initState();   
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "I dont want to bring listCurrencies many times, just once"

*FutureBuilder* is one way you can do this. It will render the widget once *listCurrencies* is populated.

Another way is to use a ternary operator

```
listCurrencies != null ? (widget using listcurrencies) : (a progress indicator)
```

Edit:

Also you should set listCurrencies using

```
setState((){
    listCurrencies = val;
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. The ternary operator was the response!
"I dont want to bring listCurrencies many times, just once" and this was, because If I added a FutureBuilder in the build I will get many times the ListOfCurrencies, and I wanted to be able to modify it in the way